# Bash file is unable to execute on linux terminal: Socket Programming

Tags: bash, terminal, gnome-terminal, xterm, terminal-multiplexer

I have written some codes for socket programming namely socket and plug. To execute them together I am trying to use the below bash file but I get the following errors.

I did execute the command `chmod +x run.sh`

When I wrote `echo $TERM` , I get `xterm`. But did not really help.

**Error:** `./run.sh: line 3: xterm: command not found` 
           `./run.sh: line 5: xterm: command not found` and so on.

---

### run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#file name: run.sh
xterm -e "./socket"
usleep 100
xterm -e "./plug 5"
xterm -e "./plug 6"
xterm -e "./plug 7"
xterm -e "./plug 8"
xterm -e "./plug 9"
xterm -e "./plug 10"
xterm -e "./plug 11"
```

I even tried replacing `xterm -e` with `gnome-terminal -x sh -c`, but I get the same errors (only gnome-terminal).

Comment: Consider using the full path from `which xterm`

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$TERM` may be set to `xterm` regardless if `xterm` is installed.

You can check if `xterm` is available first using `which xterm`. See below sample script:

```
#!/bin/bash
XTERM=$(which xterm)
FOUND=$?
if [ "$FOUND" -eq "0" ]
then
    $XTERM -e "./socket"
    usleep 100
    $XTERM -e "./plug 5"
else
    echo "XTERM does not exist"
fi
```

Or use another terminal application of your choice.

Comment: I got `XTERM does not exist`

Comment: Is xterm-256color, different then xterm

Comment: The `$TERM` variable is more used to clarify the text window capabilities. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/The-TERM-variable.html for details. This is apart from the installed terminal applications. You can use a terminal application of your choice (or install `xterm`)

Comment: How can I find out which terminal is installed on my computer? I am actually doing `ssh`

Comment: When using `ssh` why don't you use plain `./socket &` to start the socket in the background, and 'talk' to it using `./plug 5` (perhaps from another `ssh` session. This is apart from using a (graphical) terminal. An application like `xterm` is only necessary when using a graphical desktop environment, not if you use a `ssh` connection.

Comment: I did try doing that. But it did not help at all. :(